# Fetching data using NsoperationQueue in sleep mode

Tags: ios

```
I have added data fetching operations to NSOperationQueue .During the process, I just put the device to sleep mode and the process gets stopped. I surfed stack overflow an get some basic ideas.I need help to continue my fetching process without any interruption when device moves to sleep mode.Help appreciated !!


    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext=((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext;

    NSOperationQueue *downLoadQueue=((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).downloadqueue;
```

//Fetch operation

```
        if([fetchqueue count]>0)
        {
            Queue *queue=[fetchqueue objectAtIndex:0];

            queue.status=@"INP";
            [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
                NSError * error = nil;
                if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]){
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error while loading3");

                }
            }];

            DownloadOperation *downloadOp=[[DownloadOperation alloc]init];
            downloadOp.queue=queue;
            [downLoadQueue addOperation:downloadOp];

        }
    }


The downLoadQueue started its execution. It is fetching data from server meanwhile the device goes to sleep and the execution stops. I don't know how to continue in this block applicationDidEnterBackground. How can I get my lengthy downloading process during sleep mode?


Also tried this one..But the operation was not resumed.
```

//code follows
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

```
        NSOperationQueue *downLoadQueue;
        downLoadQueue=((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).downloadqueue;

        [downLoadQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished]; 

    });
}

Please suggest any ideas.
```

Comment: Please post snippet of code to get an idea of what you've attempted.

Comment: Seems you didnt create a background task object

Comment: If i do so,is there any time limitation for the task to complete? It almost took 15 mins in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is background task. Take a look at [apple docs about this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). There are also a lot of answers on stackowerflow how to implemet such feature.

I think in your case you can try next code to execute `NSOperations` a in backgraund task:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.

    //Start your NSOperationQueue if it's not executing
    //Lock current thread while operations are executing
    [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished]; 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't able to get the nsoperationqueue to continue its operation

Comment: I get the global queue in app delegate and used the  [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished ] method. but no use